# google cloud ML Engine model Version creation and set as default

Tags: json, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want to create Version for ML Engine Model by Rest API and set as default. kindly help me and suggest what is the mistake that I am doing.Sending below request and hitting the post API Below.

Trying hitting by Google Auth Playground.

Post URL : https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects//models//versions

Request Body :

```
{
  "name": "v4",
  "description": "This is test Version created by API",
  "isDefault": True,
  "deploymentUri": "gs://car-hertz/vans-uk-hertz/output/v1/F0/export/exporter/1531390162/",
  "runtimeVersion": "1.4",
  "framework": enum(TENSORFLOW),
  "pythonVersion": "2.7"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [REST API docs for the Version resource](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions#Version) you can see in the description for the `framework` field that:

> Valid values are TENSORFLOW, SCIKIT_LEARN, and XGBOOST

`enum(Framework)` is just the field's type. Also, from that same link: `isDefault` field is output only. You shouldn't include it in the request to create a model version. From the [docs for the create method](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions/create):

> If you want a new version to be the default, you must call
>   [projects.models.versions.setDefault](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions/setDefault).

So, to create a new model version and set it as default via REST API:

1. Put the request payload in a json file:

`{
  "name": "v4",
  "description": "This is test Version created by API",
  "deploymentUri": "gs://car-hertz/vans-uk-hertz/output/v1/F0/export/exporter/1531390162/",
  "runtimeVersion": "1.4",
  "framework": "TENSORFLOW",
  "pythonVersion": "2.7"
}`

2. Create the version by running in a shell the following (I like to use a gcurl alias):

`alias gcurl='curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" '`

`gcurl -X POST -T "$REQUEST_FILEPATH" https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/models/$MODEL/versions`

3. Set the above as the default:

`gcurl -X POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/models/$MODEL/versions/v4:setDefault`